# Passing the results of multiple sequential HBase queries to a Mapreduce job

Tags: graph, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have an HBase database that stores adjacency lists for a directed graph, with the edges in each direction stored in a pair of column families, where each row denotes a vertex. I am writing a mapreduce job, which takes as its input all nodes which also have an edge pointing from the same vertices as have an edge pointed at some other vertex (nominated as the subject of the query). This is a little difficult to explain, but in the following diagram, the set of nodes taken as the input, when querying on vertex 'A', would be {A, B, C}, by virtue of their all having edges from vertex '1':

[image: Example graph]

To perform this query in HBase, I first lookup the vertices with edges to 'A' in the reverse edges column family yielding {1}, and the, for every element in that set, lookup the vertices with edges from that element of the set, in the forward edges column family.

This should yield a set of key-value pairs: {1: {A,B,C}}.

Now, I would like to take the output of this set of queries and pass it to a hadoop mapreduce job, however, I can't find a way of 'chaining' hbase queries together to provide the input to a TableMapper in the Hbase mapreduce API. So far, my only idea has been to provide another initial mapper which takes the results of the first query (on the reverse edges table), for each result, performs the query on the forward edges table, and yields the results to be passed to a second map job. However, performing IO from within a map job makes me uneasy, as it seems rather counter to the mapreduce paradigm (and could lead to a bottleneck if several mappers are all trying to access HBase at once). Therefore, can anyone suggest an alternative strategy for performing this sort of query, or offer any advice about best practices for working with hbase and mapreduce in such a way? I'd also be interested to know if there's any improvements to my database schema that could mitigate this problem.

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not flowing so well with the Map/Reduce paradigm. I've seen the shortest path problem solved by many M/R chained together. This is not so efficient but needed to get the global view at the reducer level.

In your case, it seems that you could perform all the requests within your mapper by following the edges and keeping a list of seen nodes.

> However, performing IO from within a map job makes me uneasy

You should not worry about that. Your data model is absolutely random and trying to perform data locality will be extremely hard therefore you don't have much choice but to query all this data across the network. HBase is designed to handle large parallel queries. Having multiple mapper query on disjoint data will yield into a well distribution of request and a high throughput.

Make sure to keep small block size in HBase tables to optimize your reads and have as little as possible HFile for your regions. I'm assuming your data is quite static here so doing a major compaction will merge the HFile together and reduce the number of files to read.

Comment: Thanks Pierre-Luc, that's a really great answer - I hadn't considered  the characteristics of how the data are likely to be distributed across the hbase nodes, and the likely effect on query performance, this has been really instructive. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. You have an interesting problem at hand.